# NGINX Dynamic Proxy Location with ID in the URL

Tags: nginx

I have this kind of URL in my web app - `/sample/company/123/invoices/download/123`

```
location /sample/company/ {
   root /myapp/public;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_pass my-backend:8000;
}
```

If i'm having that kind of URL all pages that has this URL `/sample/company/` gets affected. I only wanted to make that rule only applicable if the URL is `/sample/company/123/invoices/download/123`. Take note that the `123` are dynamic, these are IDs.

I'm really new to NGINX.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `location` block like this:

```
location ~ ^/sample/company/[0-9]+/invoices/download/[0-9]+$ {
    root /myapp/public;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass my-backend:8000;
}
```

According to [nginx location documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) nginx first checks exact and prefix location block matches, and remembers the closest one.

Then it checks regular expression matches like above, and uses a matching one. If there is no match, it uses the exact / prefix match.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! On the last parameter, that should accept alphanumeric characters. I think the `[0-9]` means it only accepts numbers? If Yes, can we change that to accept alphanumeric and underscore? Thanks again!!

Comment: I did something like this - `location ~ ^/sample/company/[0-9]+/invoices/download/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$` and looks like it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower That regex could be simplified to `location ~ ^/sample/company/\d+/invoices/download/\w+$` meaning exactly the same.

Comment: Explicit notation of allowed characters is easier to read, one doesn't need to remember all the magic letter meanings.